# Link to all posts with same tag, using acts_as_taggable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

So I have acts_as_taggable working properly. I am able to add the tags when creating a new post and I can see all the tags when looking at the posts. What Im trying to do is create a nav link for certain tags. For instance I want a nav link that says "Movies" and when I click that link I want all the posts that I have created that have the tag "Movies" to show. This is my post_controller.rb

```
def index
  @posts = current_author.posts.most_recent
end

def show
end

def new
  @post = current_author.posts.new
end

private
  def set_post
    @post = current_author.posts.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :description, :banner_image_url, :tag_list)
  end
end

end
```

My post.rb that deals with the tags

```
acts_as_taggable # Alias for acts_as_taggable_on :tags

extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

belongs_to :author


scope :most_recent, -> { order(published_at: :desc) }
scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
scope :with_tag, -> (tag) { tagged_with(tag) if tag.present? }

scope :list_for, -> (page, tag) do
 recent_paginated(page).with_tag(tag)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom route which the nav button can link to.

```
<%= link_to "Movies, tagged_posts_path("Movies") %>
```

In posts_controller, create a method for the custom route. The custom route can use the 'with_tag' scope to return only posts tagged with 'Movies' to your view.

```
def tagged
  @posts = Post.with_tag(params[:tag])
end
```

Make sure you add the new custom route to the routes file.

```
resources :posts do
  collection do
    get "/tagged/:tag", to: "posts#tagged", as: "tagged"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this definitely has me going in the right direction. Im also wondering this, I already have my separate pages and links setup for the tags I want to use. So I already have on my nav "Movies", "TV" and "Music", they're just blank pages when you click on them. Would it just be easier to just call the tag for that specific page, instead of having to create a new route and new views template. So for instance under Movies just have a call tag @posts.tagged_with("movies").

Comment: Tweaked some things around on my code and this worked out perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: You could use the existing index route and in the controller method check for the existence of a tag parameter. The link_to method would have to pass the tag slightly differently e.g. link_to "Movies", posts_path, {tag: "Movies"}. Could be a better solution if you have lots of different tags to link to.